# Flitter. Analogue Animation.event from React Native?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

1. How to move the widget in accordance with the movement of the finger.
     Not Drag'n'Drop?
2. Make swipe (not Dismissible)?

Although would be in which direction to look?

Comment: You may want to use `Listener` widget

Comment: What to move Widget through? Animation or just State?

Comment: There are many solutions. `Stack`+`Positionned` is one. `Align` is another. Or `Overlay`+`Positionned`

Comment: Do I need to link animations and gestures to move the widget or is it a bad practice and use only the State?